# Change Form Backgroundimage takes too much memory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory

I create a little game in windows forms, and I use the property backgroudimage.
I create new Bitmaps and gives it to the form.
The problem is, the program is use too much memory-every time its do the proccess of making new Bitmap it adds more 2k!
After a while i guess the garbage collector remove them all (the memory drops at once), but it can get to 800k and it's ridiculous for my little game.
I don't have any refernce to the Bitmap after i put it to the form property, and even when i put the bitmap to null the problem isn't solved.
What can I do in order to fix that memory problem? Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note, .NET doesn't see any problem with memory, so it won't clear it out. If you overload Windows with applications, it will go down. But don't be frightened of it using 'too much' memory. It will clean it when necessary. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: roken you right, next time i will do as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Get a reference to the previous image before setting the new one, so that you can dispose it:

```
Image oldImage = this.BackgroundImage;
this.BackgroundImage = newImage;
oldImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: I really don't know why, but it has no influence on the memory (the function Dispose()).

Comment: @liran63: If you create new images, it's normal for the memory usage to grow. The garbage collector will only do a cleanup when it's needed or if there is spare time to use. The `Dispose` call doesn't free any memory in itself, but it make the cleanup easier as the objects doesn't have to go the process of being finalised.

Comment: Yep, thats right - Dispose is like a 'I've cleaned up everything I need to, so don't tidy up my unmanaged resources'. It's because Dispose normally has a call to GC.SuppressFinalize(this), which means it doesn't have to do any additional work to tidy up stuff. You've saved it the trouble